# NDSolver cannot give precise result for extremely small values

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I would like to solve an ODE with MMA. The equation is simply the Coulomb law. However, I cannot get a satisfying result:

```
m0 = 9.1 10^-31;
\[Epsilon] = 8.8 10^-12;
e = 1.6 10^-19;
Q = 10^27 e;
c = 3 10^8;

NDSolve[{m0/Sqrt[1 - (R'[t]/c)^2] R''[t] == -1/(4 \[Pi] \[Epsilon]) Q/
    R[t]^2, R'[0] == 0.85 c, R[0] == 1}, R, {t, 0, 1}]
```

The left hand side of the equation is very small, so MMA cannot correctly converge.

Comment: I think you need to rescale the ode. You have speed of light in there and also numbers as small as 10^-31 all in the same equation.   No wonder even Mathematica is having hard time.  Here is a whole book on scaling of differential equations [Scaling of Differential
Equations](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-319-32726-6.pdf)

Comment: `NDSolve[{m0/Sqrt[1 - (R'[t]/c)^2] R''[t] == -1/(4 \[Pi] \[Epsilon]) Q/
      R[t]^2, R'[0] == 0.85 c, R[0] == 1}, R, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
Plot[R[t] /. %[[1]], {t, 0, 2.25*10^-38}]` ?

Comment: What is dissatisfying about the result? Or: what do you hope to get?

Comment: @Michael E2 The result is non-physical.

Comment: I don't know what that means in this case.  What would a physical result look like?

Comment: To mention again what has already been mentioned, with some clarification for the OP: your constants vary by nearly 40 orders of magnitude, from -31 to 8; you must understand that when using machine precision numerical algorithms, this will cause you the problems you are encountering. This was stated by Nasser and they give a link to a great reference text that will serve you well to overcome this problem.